# What food are the players served in a break?

Tags: cricket

What food are the players served with, during a test match? I am asking this since they have to play game for 3-4 hours from the lunch time as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It completely depends on the venue. A "traditional" cricket tea in the UK & Ireland would consist of sandwiches, cakes and scones, with hot tea, but traditions vary across the world.

In general, though, the venue provides the catering, and what's served depends on cost, budget, dietary requirements of players & officials and tradition.

Comment: Given the question specifically refers to Test Matches I suspect budget isnt much of a consideration.

Comment: True, but I reckon the catering budget varies wildly from country to country, so it would come in to it somewhere along the line

Comment: Shane Warne was known for having a Meat Pie. Most players now days have healthier preferences.

Answer (score 1):

When the match has lunch and tea, Lunch is usually a warm meal, with Tea being sandwiches, cakes etc.

Lunch would typically be something like pasta or perhaps chicken and rice.  The last all day game I umpired in we had a chicken currey with Rice.

Comment: What experience do you have umpiring at the Test Match level, which is what the question is asking about?